# Fetch requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a React app which communicates with the server. At some moment I have screen as follows:

[image]

Thus, on this screen I have three components and every one needs to get data from the server.

- One `fetch` for total cars in the basket (top right)
- One `fetch` for the counters in the left navigation (left)
- One `fetch` for current cars in the basket (middle)

Thus three `fetch` requests in one screen. Is it a good idea?

Is there a better approach?

Comment: It's absolutely normal I guess. And inside `.then` of each `fetch` you may call `setState` and update the UI

Comment: Three requests aren't that bad.

Comment: Making fewer requests is generally considered better, but it has a cost. I'd say don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: Alternatively you can use graphql  from facebook .One fetch to get all the needed info from server .....This will give good performance in your case than to make individual request... Facebook is using this for thier site

Comment: That's 3 fetch on a full page load, but I expect that when you subsequently, say, navigate to another page (your middle component), then you'd only fetch data for *that* component and not again for the cart or navigation (unless they're impacted). So nothing wrong with that imo.